# Angular date filter displaying undefined/NaN even with ng-cloak

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im displaying a formatted date using angular date filter. The date string is loaded via ajax request and turned into a `Date` object by a method on the controller.

```
<div ng-cloak class="blog-post">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ toDate(post.created_timestamp) | date:'mediumDate' }} by {{ post.author }}</p>

    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>

blogControllers.controller('BlogDetailController', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams',
function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
    $http.get('/api/blog/post/' + $routeParams.postId).success(function (data) {
        $scope.post = data;
    });

    /**
     * Turn the string into a Date object
     * @param date
     * @returns {Date}
     */
    $scope.toDate = function(date) {
        return new Date(Date.parse(date));
    }
}]);
```

Before the ajax request loads the browser is displaying `undefined NaN, NaN` for the date even though I'm using `ng-cloak`. If I put ng-cloak on the p tag it has no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you got `undefined NaN, NaN` is because your

```
$scope.toDate = function(date) {
        return new Date(Date.parse(date));
    }
```

function will always return something, you may want to check the 'date' that passed in like this:

```
   $scope.toDate = function(date) {
       if(date)
        return new Date(Date.parse(date));
       else
           return null;
    }
```

it maybe hard to hide the div by using ng-cloak as you got some static content(like 'by') in it. and ng-show will be easier.

try

```
<div ng-show="post">
    <h2 class="blog-post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
    <p class="blog-post-meta">{{ toDate(post.created_timestamp) | date:'mediumDate' }} by {{ post.author }}</p>

    <p>{{ post.content }}</p>
</div>
```

the div will only show when you assign value to 'post' in controller

Comment: Both solutions worked on their own. I went with ng-show since this seems more like a view responsibility. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First thing i suggest you try is to check if the function $scope.toDate(data) returns the expected value. i.e pass in the `post.created_timestamp` to the function and see what is being returned.

if you get the right value. Also if it also returns a timestamp, instead of converting it you can just add the timestamp with the filter.

reference: [Angularjs date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

The ngCloak directive is used to prevent the Angular html template from being briefly displayed by the browser in its raw (uncompiled) form while your application is loading.
[Angularjs Ng cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)